# Manipulating DOM model of foreign domain via installed plugin in chrome and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dom, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

It's a question more of a "Is it possible / What technologies to be applied".

I have a website on domaina.com, I have Chrome extension installed, which can read/modify domain's DOM, the extension, as I understand can be connected via something like `https://github.com/substack/node-browserify` to NodeJS on the server-side, and then use something like CasperJS for Node to manipulate that very same DOM model and return it.

The mission is to build macros and automation tools for the website, but Node scripts reside on domainb.com

Is this something doable? Can you point to specific packages of Node or documentation of how t o accomplish this?

This question should not raise any arguments, so I think it's ok to post it here.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: So you want to call the node.js scripts reside on domainB.com to manipulate DomainA's DOMs via some plugin installed in your chrome, right? Can you edit DomainB's scripts?

Comment: Right. Yes I have full control of the domainb server and scripts.

Comment: Why not use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) in DomainB's node.js scripts to manipulate DomainA's DOM directly? I think the Chrome plugin is NOT necessary.